# Google Play Store Publish to Production

Tags: android, google-play

I have had an app in Google Play Store **Beta**, and submitted it to **Production** about an hour ago. In the Google Play Console, it shows that it's published to **Production**, however in the Play Store itself, the published version still shows as `(Beta)`.

**Question**

1. Will the app eventually be rolled out to **Production**? Or is there something I still need to do?
2. How long does it take to roll out to **Production**?

Thank you.

Comment: It usually takes a couple of hours to reflect. You are seeing the beta version because you must be enrolled as a beta tester. Check from some external viewers profile or maybe share the link and i can check.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am a beta tester, and you're correct, if I access it from another browser, it shows it's in production.  Thank you!...  here's my app anyway www.thewhozoo.com

Comment: Yup shows into Prod :) I will post this as an answer so that you can accept :)

Comment: Will do :)  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually takes a couple of hours to reflect. You are seeing the beta version because you must be enrolled as a beta tester. Check from some external viewers profile and it should show.

Answer (score 0):

And also please check if **Managed publishing ON**

When you send your changes to Google for review, you'll need to publish them **manually** after they're approved.